# sass --interactive returns FormatException: Could not find an option named "interactive"

Tags: sass, rubygems, dart, gulp-sass

I've get a FormatException error every time i try to invoke the sass interactive shell. Please does anyone know the reason for this and how it can be resolved. i've tried googling but all i get is syntax errors and nothing about this. please find below the error message returned.
thanks in advance for your help.

```
 my_username$ sass --interactive
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:1436
if(this===init.globalState.e)throw u}}finally{this.cy=x
                             ^

FormatException: Could not find an option named "interactive".
    at b (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:1916:3)
    at q (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:1922:23)
    at iu.fo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:6358:14)
    at iu.aC (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:6256:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:8058:42
    at uM.a (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3050:72)
    at uM.dart.uM.$2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3146:24)
    at tU.dart.tU.$1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3142:31)
    at tn.fv (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3380:41)
    at qv.$0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3329:16)
```

Comment: I'd create a bug report in https://github.com/sass/dart-sass, but it requires all the information to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Dart Sass, which doesn't (currently) support the `--interactive` flag. Feel free to file a feature request, though!